# Create an ARGB struct for C header from a PNG

Tags: x11, graphics, imagemagick, image-manipulation, graphicmagick

I need to update a logo bitmap to an updated logo. The existing code uses a C header which is loaded via `XChangeProperty`.

I have looked into imagemagick and the Gimp in order to convert the updated png I have into a suitable header. Gimp even said 'export a C header' (or something like it) but the result did not resemble the existing format.

How do I go (preferably on the command-line) from a png to a suitable header file?

*Edit:* Expanding the question a little, the (now out of date) logo I would like to replace is [in this file](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/modules/X11/rlogo_icon.h) and [gets used here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/modules/X11/devX11.c#L1604-L1609).

Comment: Which property is this? Can you guess the format of the old file or post the beginning? From your earlier comment, it looks like there's a size followed by some bitmap data, is there other meta-information besides the size? How many colors?

Comment: I can point you to the code. I once received this as a patch for package I maintain for Debian and then guided it upstream -- but I am a little ignorant as to how it got created. And the gentleman who created it hasn't replied to a recent email question I sent ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ImageMagick, based on [rlogo_icon.h](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/modules/X11/rlogo_icon.h).

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'unsigned long rlogo_icon[] = {'
identify -format '%w, %h,' $1
convert $1 -color-matrix '0 0 1 0, 0 1 0 0, 1 0 0 0, 0 0 0 1' RGBA:- | hexdump -v -e '1/4 "0x%08x,\n"'
echo '};'
```

Usage:

```
./script.sh rlogo_icon.png > rlogo_icon.h
```

I'm not sure this `-color-matrix` is always correct.  I placed bytes in the order of BGRA because my computer is little endian.

Comment: That worked!  You are my hero!  Thanks so much!  (I also had to edit the code to account for the 200x155 size which I failed last time around when trying the first suggestion (by @Gilles, IIRC).